# How does a PC detect a VGA monitor?

Tags: rgb, vga

Currently I am trying to connect my LCD to my laptop through a VGA connector. The LCD has 6 wires out of it which I am trying to solder to a VGA male connector, But the laptop doesn't detect the LCD. What is wrong?

I noticed that the laptop can detect other screen even if they are turned off (no power cable attached), so I think the trick is in the wiring.

What I want to know is how a PC detects the VGA monitor once its connected.
Does it send a signal that the monitor respond to?

My LCD 6-wires are labled [HOUT - ROUT - GOUT - BOUT - SYN - VC0].
I assumed ROUT, BOUT and GOUT are the RGB signals, SYN is the VSYNC and HOUT to be the HSYNC. (Not sure of that though).

Comment: Do you have more information about the LCD?

Comment: There is a strong possibility that if it is a panel from a device like a DVD player, that it is not VGA at all. Without information on the display it is impossible to say what protocol it uses, and just hooking it up to a VGA connector and hoping is a good way of breaking the display or worse your computer.

Comment: Related to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134674/how-vga-monitor-detects-video-resolution

Answer (score 5):

Computers detect screens by something called [Display Data Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel)

It's a low rate data signal on four pins in the VGA connector that tells the computer about its presence, allowed modes and frequencies, etc.

You can still use a screen without DDC, but you need some pull-up or pull-down resistors to tell the computer there's a screen at all. You'll also have to force the adapter to produce the signal, and you'll have to set up the monitor parameters manually.

Comment: Isn't the LCD supposed to have those resistors built-in?
What pins are those resistors connected to?
Can you provide some more details??

Comment: Actually it's an LCD I pulled out of a DVD player I had. I don't have much details for it.
For the moment, I just need the laptop to detect its presence, even if the image is distorted or no-image at all. one step at a time.

Answer (score 4):

A simple, easy way that may work is to ground the VGA out pins 4, 11 (DDC 0/2), which will put the display mode to > 1024x768 color. I have a HDMI-VGA converter that uses the DDC pins to detect the presence of the monitor, and turn on/off the audio output (it also extracts audio from HDMI) accordingly.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but hoping you can help. Using the pinout [here](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15_pinout.shtml), are you saying to connect 4 TO 11, or connect 4 AND 11 to 5?

Comment: @LuckySpoon "ground the VGA out pins 4, 11" means connecting both pins 4 and 11 to GND (pin 5). All 3 pins shall be connected together.