# Cheap hack works, but I need a VGA cable plugged in

Tags: audio, hdmi

My laptop headphone jack died.  I purchased an HDMI to VGA dongle with an audio out port and it works, but only when I have a VGA cable plugged into the dongle. Why? Can I short out two pins with a paper clip and make it work that way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170546/how-does-a-pc-detect-a-vga-monitor

Comment: You can get a USB to audio adapter and it might be less of a hack than using HDMI

Answer (score 4):

The HDM to VGA adaptor needs to determine the pixel count and scan rate for the VGA output, to do this it uses EDID this is an I<sup>2</sup>C EEPROM  SDA on pin 12, SCL on pin 8, 5V on pin 9, and ground on pin 5.

Comment: To supplement this, there’s a whole industry supplying the need for “dummy vga plug” - a quick search turns up plug and play solutions that implement the eeprom for you.